# play animation once instead of looping three.js

Tags: html, animation, three.js, blender

I have exported blender JSON animation into THREE.js,
everything works fine, but I want to play the animation only once and stop instead of looping the animation.

Answer (score 15):

Old question, but in case anyone needs it the solution is to set `animation.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce)`

```js
let objLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

objLoader.load('./your.json', function(obj)
{
  scene.add(obj);

  let animationMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(obj);
  let animation = animationMixer.clipAction(obj.animations[0]);
  animation.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
  animation.clampWhenFinished = true;
  animation.enable = true;

  animation.play();
})
```

I'm referring to ThreeJS `r84`.

Comment: I found I needed to do a `reset` after the `play`, so `animation.play().reset();`

Comment: It might work to first call `play` and then `reset`, but the regular and safer way is to do the `reset`-call first, like this: `animation.reset().play()`. (The documentation also suggests this https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationAction.play).

Answer (score 1):

Set the `loop` property on the `Animation` object to false.

documentation here: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Animation/Animation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you type LoopOnce NOT loopOnce (as I did). Took me hours to spot that one (no error message).