# How can an AnimationAction stop at the last frame without looping in three.js?

Tags: animation, three.js, morphing

I'd like to stop an AnimationAction at the last frame that I've created with morph targets.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationAction

I've tried `animationAction.clampWhenFinished = true;` but that doesn't seem to work.

I've looked at older [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959167/play-animation-once-instead-of-looping-three-js) and searched through [forums](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8446) but the solutions didn't work.

```
var cubeTarget1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 10, 10);
var cubeTarget2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 10, 50);
var cubeTarget3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(60, 10, 10);

cubeGeometry.morphTargets[0] = {name: 't1', vertices: cubeTarget1.vertices};
cubeGeometry.morphTargets[1] = {name: 't2', vertices: cubeTarget2.vertices};
cubeGeometry.morphTargets[2] = {name: 't3', vertices: cubeTarget3.vertices};
```

Is there a way I can do something like: (this doesn't work, it loops back to the first morphTarget)

```
var clip1 = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence('run', [cubeGeometry.morphTargets[0],cubeGeometry.morphTargets[1]], 30);
var action1 = mixer.clipAction(clip1);
action1.play(); // starts at cubeTarget1 ends at cubeTarget2 (animating between them, without a loop)

// and at a later point I'd like to do

var clip2 = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence('run', [cubeGeometry.morphTargets[1],cubeGeometry.morphTargets[2]], 30);
var action2 = mixer.clipAction(clip2);
action2.play(); // starts at cubeTarget2 ends at cubeTarget3 (animating between them, without a loop)
```

Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/uy8abk6v/

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach that I used with an enemy bot gltf model on my three.js prototype first person shooter. The robot has a single track animation with many frames. I had to split the frames up into sub clips with the following code then applied clampwhenfinished.

```
var EnemyHeavyBotFallBackClip = THREE.AnimationUtils.subclip(gltf.animations[0], “Take_001”, 1300, 1355);
actionEnemyHeavyBotFallBackMixer = mixer.clipAction(EnemyHeavyBotFallBackClip);
actionEnemyHeavyBotFallBackMixer.clampWhenFinished = true;
actionEnemyHeavyBotFallBackMixer.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
actionEnemyHeavyBotFallBackMixer.play();
```

https://www.shanebrumback.com/super-soldier-battle-intro.html

Disclaimer:  This is my website.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the three.js code. And inside LoopOnce the section involving clampWhenFinished doesn't get hit at all.

For now I'll do it in a very crude way until I find a better solution:

```
action.setDuration(5).play(); 
setTimeout(function()
{
    action.paused = true;
},2500); // half of the duration
```

Another way I've been doing is to use morphTargetInfluences and just increment it on an animation loop:

```
function animate() {
  if (cube.morphTargetInfluences[0] < 1)
    cube.morphTargetInfluences[0] += 0.01;

  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Use Tween.js if you need more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to get this working, a lot of the online examples seem to be outdated and/or non-working. Try:

```js
var clips = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateClipsFromMorphTargetSequences(geometry.morphAttributes.position, 60, true);
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(points);
var action = mixer.clipAction(clips[0]).setDuration(10);
action.clampWhenFinished = true;
action.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
action.play();
```

Note the "noLoop" parameter of CreateClipsFromMorphTargetSequences(name: String, morphTargetSequence: Array, fps: Number, **noLoop: Boolean**) needs to be "true" along with clampWhenFinished = true and setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce).

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/jm4ersoq/